# Azure Web Apps: Removing FTP access

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

I cannot find where on the portal I originally created this FTP access account. I wish to delete it. Where can this be done?

[image: FTP Credentials]

Comment: I dont think you can delete those settings, in terms of "I don't want this stuff displayed here anymore". You can only do as mentioned below by QFDev and that is to fully disable FTP for your app. I think in some time you'll be able to disable this through the Azure CLI as well as ARM templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In "**Application Settings**"  blade there's now an option to restrict to FTPS or fully disable.

[image: Azure - Application Settings]

Answer (score 2):

Starting May 8th 2018, a new setting is available to enable or disable FTP/FTPS. You can read more about it at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2018/05/08/web-apps-making-changes-to-ftp-deployments/

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue in Azure App Service. I believe that Azure team will add this feature in the future. You can check this link: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/8211222-option-to-disable-ftp-and-force-ftps-in-azure-we for status.

Answer (score 0):

In latest Azure these options are changed,
Now its **App Service** > **Configuration**(its part of Settings in left pane) > **General Settings** (Tab on the Top) > **FTP State** and than Save it

[image]